# Permutation Problem

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinations

I am struck very badly in a problem. my problem goes this way; I need to find permutations of n objects(there could be repetitions) such a way that every permutation differs from the other by atleast k objects.

For ex: if there are 5 objects a,b,c,d,e and each permutation differs by 2 or more object and if aabcd is a permutation then I cannot have aabdd as a permutation as both differ by just one object.

If anyone can point me out a general formula or procedure to solve this problem, I'd be highly grateful

Thanks for your time and consideration of this request

--Ady

Comment: And when is this homework due?

Comment: Neither aabcd nor aabdd is a permutation of abcde. A permutation is the exact same things in a possibly different order. Also, your clue word might be "Hamming distance"?

Comment: The problem you describe sounds more like sampling with replacment. Given `N` objects, choose `M` with replacement such that
each sample must differ from the previously selected samples by at least `K` objects.
I suspect generate-and-test is the solution. It isn't pretty, it isn't efficient and it won't be fast. In fact it may scale exponentially with respect to `M`

Comment: You need to be more precise about what exactly is required.

Comment: Do you consider `aabcd` and e.g. `bcdaa` differing in 5 "objects" or the same? In other words, does order matter (permutation) or not (combination)?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I will try repeating, I have to generate permutations (with repitation) of length 'n' using [a ... z] such that each permutation differs from the other by at-least 'k' literals w.r.t to relative position; 

for ex: if n=5, k= 2 then abaca, abaac, caaba are valid permutations as they differ by at-least two literals w.r.t relative position; while abaca, abacb are not as they differ by only one. 

my Q is how do is approach this problem for a given n and k, how do i determine total number of permutations possible. Thanks

--Ady

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's related to Conway's Lexicode thereom.  I heard him give a lecture about it once.  It was quite entertaining.
http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/seminars/Kuwait/abstracts/L25.pdf

Comment: thanks for the above, its indeed interesting, could you pls describe more. I am not able to deduce anything from it